# Struggling with a model because of a lot of data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-design, activerecord

I'm building an app to write wine tasting notes, and I have to translate this [tasting framework](http://www.wsetglobal.com/documents/l3_wine_satcard_2012_eng_new.pdf) (only the first page) into a model.

It's a lot of a data and I'm not sure about how to proceed. I tried to sketch a possible solution in [this spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AozgbHd_TEeodDRpSl9uc2liLThpUF9uNE1uVG1RZUE&usp=sharing).

What would you suggest to do? Should I create only one model (Wine) with a column for each wine characteristic?

Thanks!

P.S. I'm learning web development, sorry if my question sounds trivial.

Comment: you can serialize your data and keep in in 1 column. Or at least group and then serialize

Comment: I think your models are fine. Serializing will make your code more complex and less comprehensive.

Comment: @Pierre-LouisGottfrois I've received a lot of different feedback in these days, all different from each other :)
Anyway, yesterday I talked with a guy who works as a database administrator in a Italian big company and he suggested me to create a different model for each property in order to get a more flexible db. [Here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44421777/vindemio_db.pdf) is the result.

Would like to hear your opinions.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps not a direct answer to your question but here's a few notes nevertheless:

I'd say for something like wine tasting, I would go for a combination of selects, tags and simple free-text.

[This RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging) should give you a good introduction to the [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on) gem for tagging.

One thing that may be handy when modelling your DB is to look at several wine tasting 'forms' that are already filled out and see if you can see a pattern. Say for Palate/Acidity I would expect the value to be one of light/medium/high, whereas for the Conclusion/Identity it could be pretty much anything.

You'll also need to find the right balance between restricting and allowing the user input. I'd expect your users to be happier with free-text and feeling more restricted with select/radio boxes. On the other hand, it is always easier (for you) to change from a select box to free text, rather than the other way around. Not to mention searching is much easier by selects or tags.

I don't think your question is that trivial and I think you should to simply try it and see.  And design with the ability to change in mind.